# UTF-16 Encoding - Why using complex surrogate pairs?

Tags: string, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16

I have been working on string encoding schemes and while I examine how UTF-16 works, I have a question. Why using complex surrogate pairs to represent 21 bits code point? Why not to simply store the bits in the first code unit and the remaining bits in the second code unit? Am I missing something! Is there a problem to store the bits directly like we did in UTF-8?

Example of what I am thinking of:

The character ''

Corresponding code point: 128579 (Decimal)
The binary form: `1 1111 0110 0100 0011` (17 bits)
It's 17-bit code point.

- Based on UTF-8 schemes, it will be represented as:

  ```
  240 : 11110 000
  159 : 10 011111
  153 : 10 011001
  131 : 10 000011
  ```
- In UTF-16, why not do something looks like that rather than using surrogate pairs:

  ```
  49159 : 110 0 0000 0000 0111
  30275 : 01 11 0110 0100 0011
  ```

Comment: Which bits do you store in the first unit?  Which bits do you store in the second unit?  How do you know that what you're dealing with is a 21-bit number, not two 16-bit numbers (code points)?  You have to be able to determine unambiguously when you have a surrogate pair.  That's what the UTF-16 encoding does.  It's also why the maximum Unicode code point is U+10FFFF — you can't encode anything bigger with just two surrogates with the scheme as presently designed.

Comment: Also, you are mistaken about UTF-8; it uses a similar scheme to store 21-bit numbers in 8-bit chars. In fact, UTF-8 is more complex than UTF-16, because it uses four different encodings (with four different lengths) for the various codepoints, rather than only two different ones as UTF-16 does.

Comment: Please look at the question again, I have edited it.

Comment: With regards to your edit; that is exactly how UTF-16 works. The only difference is that it subtracts 65536 from the value before dividing the bits over the two words, in 10 bits each. So `110110 0000111101` and `11011 11001000011`.

Comment: Okaaay, can you explain your comment a little bit more and why did we subtract our value from specifically 65536? What's the problem with the solution I have done above!

Comment: There's also a historical dimension: UTF-16 (then called UCS2) was already in use when it was decided that 2 bytes (65536 code points) wasn't enough. At that point, the surrogate pair solution was invented and they reserved two ranges that were still unused. If you think UTF-16 is intricate, the answer might be that it wasn't designed like this from the beginning.

Comment: Sorry  but I didn't got it. Why did we subtract our value from 65536? I want to figure out what is the problem with the representation I have done above!

Comment: We subtract 65536 because otherwise the first 65536 code points would be representable as either a single 16-bit code unit or as a surrogate pair.  That's wasteful, so we start the surrogate pair representation at the code point following the highest 16-bit code point

Comment: @MrLister... wow, this is the first time I've heard the claim that UTF-8 is more complex than UTF-16 :)  I guess that depends on your definition of the word "complex"

Comment: And why not to represent the 17-bit code point as I did above in my example!

Comment: I guess I got it. If we follow the representation algorithm in my example, we cannot determine whether a code unit encodes a single character or it is just the first or second part of a supplementary character (17- to 21- bit character code point).

Comment: I'm glad you got it, because I had no idea what I could say that hasn't been said before about Unicode.

Comment: @MrLister. Actually your comments are totally misleading but thank you for trying.

Comment: Can you point out what my comments are saying that is misleading? If I said something that can be misinterpreted, I apologise.

Comment: @MrLister. It's okay. You have said "UTF-8 is more complex than UTF-16"! You also was keeping explaining UTF-16 process rather than answering my only question! "What's the wrong with the representation I have done above". I was only looking for a direct answer for my question. Anyway thanks again.

Answer (score 11):

#### Proposed alternative to UTF-16

I think you're proposing an alternative format using 16-bit code units analogous to the UTF-8 code scheme — let's designate it UTF-EMF-16.

In your UTF-EMF-16 scheme, code points from U+0000 to U+7FFF would be encoded as a single 16-bit unit with the MSB (most significant bit) always zero.  Then, you'd reserve 16-bit units with the 2 most significant bits set to `10` as 'continuation units', with 14 bits of payload data.  And then you'd encode code points from U+8000 to U+10FFFF (the current maximum Unicode code point) in 16-bit units with the three most significant bits set to `110` and up to 13 bits of payload data. With Unicode as currently defined (U+0000 .. U+10FFFF), you'd never need more than 7 of the 13 bits set.

```
U+0000 .. U+7FFF   — One 16-bit unit: values 0x0000 .. 0x7FFF
U+8000 .. U+10FFF  — Two 16-bit units:
                     1. First unit  0xC000 .. 0xC043
                     2. Second unit 0x8000 .. 0xBFFF
```

For your example code point, U+1F683 (binary: 1 1111 0110 0100 0011):

```
First unit:  1100 0000 0000 0111 = 0xC007
Second unit: 1011 0110 0100 0011 = 0xB643
```

The second unit differs from your example in reversing the two most significant bits, from `01` in your example to `10` in mine.

#### Why wasn't such a scheme used in UTF-16

Such a scheme could be made to work.  It is unambiguous.  It could accommodate many more characters than Unicode currently allows.  UTF-8 could be modified to become UTF-EMF-8 so that it could handle the same extended range, with some characters needing 5 bytes instead of the current maximum of 4 bytes. UTF-EMF-8 with 5 bytes would encode up to 26 bits; UTF-EMF-16 could encode 27 bits, but should be limited to 26 bits (roughly 64 million code points, instead of just over 1 million).  So, why wasn't it, or something very similar, adopted?

The answer is the very common one – history (plus backwards compatibility).

When Unicode was first defined, it was hoped or believed that a 16-bit code set would be sufficient.  The UCS2 encoding was developed using 16-bit values, and many values in the range 0x8000 .. 0xFFFF were given meanings.  For example, U+FEFF is the byte order mark.

When the Unicode scheme had to be extended to make Unicode into a bigger code set, there were many defined characters with the `10` and `110` bit patterns in the most significant bits, so backwards compatibility meant that the UTF-EMF-16 scheme outlined above could not be used for UTF-16 without breaking compatibility with UCS2, which would have been a serious problem.

Consequently, the standardizers chose an alternative scheme, where there are high surrogates and low surrogates.

```
0xD800 .. 0xDBFF   High surrogates (most signicant bits of 21-bit value)
0xDC00 .. 0xDFFF   Low surrogates (less significant bits of 21-bit value)
```

The low surrogates range provides storage for 10 bits of data — the prefix `1101 11` uses 6 of 16 bits.  The high surrogates range also provides storage for 10 bits of data — the prefix `1101 10` also uses 6 of 16 bits.  But because the BMP (Basic Multilingual Plane — U+0000 .. U+FFFF) doesn't need to be encoded with two 16-bit units, the UTF-16 encoding subtracts `1` from the high order data, and can therefore be used to encode U+10000 .. U+10FFFF.  (Note that although Unicode is a 21-bit encoding, not all 21-bit (unsigned) numbers are valid Unicode code points.  Values from 0x110000 .. 0x1FFFFF are 21-bit numbers but are not a part of Unicode.)

From the Unicode [FAQ — UTF-8, UTF-16, UTF-32 & BOM](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html):

> Q: What’s the algorithm to convert from UTF-16 to character codes?
>
> A: The Unicode Standard used to contain a short algorithm, now there is just a bit distribution table. Here are three short code snippets that translate the information from the bit distribution table into C code that will convert to and from UTF-16.
>
> Using the following type definitions
>
> ```
> typedef unsigned int16 UTF16;
> typedef unsigned int32 UTF32;
> ```
>
> the first snippet calculates the high (or leading) surrogate from a character code C.
>
> ```
> const UTF16 HI_SURROGATE_START = 0xD800
>
> UTF16 X = (UTF16) C;
> UTF32 U = (C >> 16) & ((1 << 5) - 1);
> UTF16 W = (UTF16) U - 1;
> UTF16 HiSurrogate = HI_SURROGATE_START | (W << 6) | X >> 10;
> ```
>
> where X, U and W correspond to the labels used in Table 3-5 UTF-16 Bit Distribution. The next snippet does the same for the low surrogate.
>
> ```
> const UTF16 LO_SURROGATE_START = 0xDC00
>
> UTF16 X = (UTF16) C;
> UTF16 LoSurrogate = (UTF16) (LO_SURROGATE_START | X & ((1 << 10) - 1));
> ```
>
> Finally, the reverse, where hi and lo are the high and low surrogate, and C the resulting character
>
> ```
> UTF32 X = (hi & ((1 << 6) -1)) << 10 | lo & ((1 << 10) -1);
> UTF32 W = (hi >> 6) & ((1 << 5) - 1);
> UTF32 U = W + 1;
>
> UTF32 C = U << 16 | X;
> ```
>
> A caller would need to ensure that C, hi, and lo are in the appropriate ranges. [

Comment: Thanks for your time. So it's all about "backward compatibility" and by using my schema I will not be able to determine whether this code unit encodes a single character or it's a part of surrogate pairs. But I wonder what if two consecutive single character code units begin with the same mark of the surrogate pairs?

Comment: Your scheme could be used and would be unambiguous — but it wouldn't be backwards compatible with UCS2 whereas UTF-16 is backwards compatible.  Yes, lots of odd decisions are made because of 'backwards compatibility'.  It's a very common reason for what might otherwise be deemed 'non-obvious' design decisions.

Comment: What if two consecutive single character code units begin with the same style as they are surrogate pairs?

For example, these characters:

55357 : 1101100000111101
56899 : 1101111001000011

How we will know that these representations are for single characters not surrogate pairs!

Comment: You've misencoded the data. In the hypothetical UTF-EMF-16 encoding, decimal 55357 would be encoded with two units — as would any other Unicode character from U+8000 (hex) upwards. So, too, would decimal 56899 (and, indeed, U+55357 and U+56899, in hex). Further, decimal 55357 is U+D83D and decimal 56899 is U+DE43. That's a high surrogate and a low surrogate in UTF-16. Those are reserved, permanently unassigned code points under the UTF-EMF-16 encoding. No valid UTF-EMF-16 data would ever encode any of the surrogates U+D800 .. U+DFFF (any more than valid UTF-8 ever contains encoded surrogates).

Comment: Finally  Code points U+10000(65,536) to U+10FFFFF(1,114,111), hold the supplementary characters. The supplementary characters are encoded as consecutive pairs of code units. Each of the values in such an encoding pair falls into a range of 2048 "unused values" of the basic multilingual plane (code points U+0000(0) to U+FFFF(65,535)), called the surrogates area(U+D800(55296) to U+DBFF(56319) for the first code unit(high surrogate), U+DC00(56320) to U+DFFF(57343) for the second code unit(low surrogate)). Thanks so much 

Comment: I finally understand why Unicode did the surrogate pair. Thanks for that answer

Comment: I was struggling to understand how 2*10 bits could store 21 bits in surrogate pairs; you explained this perfectly with the addition hack, big thanks!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : this proposal is close to ridiculous, because you're slicing the main UniHan block right in the middle … and even if they were to re-assign code points for everything, the basic UniHan block is already `84.17 %` of your `8^5 - 1` proposal, leaving fewer than 5185 code points for everything else deemed important enough to avoid surrogating ( i still haven't subtracted out the`ASCII` portion)

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto — I carefully showed why the proposal is not really sensible, and now you're complaining that it isn't sensible?  And that's independent of any slicing of blocks of code points, which was absolutely not a consideration.

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph : think cartesian product - total unicode code points is `1114112`, or `4^8 + 4^10`. `4^8` is the BMP, `4^10`- the supp ones that require surrogating. `4^10 = 2^20 = 32^4`. high-surrogates start at `0xD800`, aka `4^5 x 54`; width is `10-bits = 4^5 = 32^2`. low-surr start at `0xDC00`, aka `4^5 x 55`; width is `10-bits = 4^5 = 4^4 x 4 = 32^2`. (`4^4 = 256`). hi-surr (`4^5 combinations `) ***cartesian product*** low-surr (`4^5 combinations`) = `( 4 ^ 5 ) ^ 2 = 4 ^ ( 5 * 2 ) = 4 ^ 10 = 32 ^ 4 =  4^(4+4) x 4 x 4 =  ( 32 ^ 2 ) ^ 2 = 32 ^ ( 2 x 2 ) = 32 ^ 4`. does this make sense ?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : does it make any sense that upper case letters don't need surrogating but lower case ones do ? if that sounds ridiculous, that's what you're proposing with UniHan . i'm all for improvements to UTF-8, but not when you're splitting core linguistic blocks in the middle - and that's true for any linguistic block, not just UniHan.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto: This is not a proposal — it is a demolition of a proposal.  And an explanation of how UTF-16 surrogates are encoded.  In order to ensure that I had not misunderstood the question, I had to explain what I understood the question was asking about, and expand on what that would mean, before explaining why it was not used.

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph :  `UTF-8` is actually *very* straight-forward if you look at every single cutoff/threshold as combinations of the number 4 :    `128 = 4 * ( 4 + 4 ) * 4` ::::::::: `192 = 4 ^ 4 - 4 * 4 * 4` ::::::::: `224 = 4 ^ 4 - ( 4 + 4 ) * 4` ::::::::: `240 = 4 ^ 4 - 4 * 4` ::::::::: `1,024 = 4 ^ 4 * 4` ::::::::: `2,048 = 4 ^ 4 * ( 4 + 4 )` ::::::::: `4,096 = ( 4 + 4 ) ^ 4` ::::::::: `0xD800 = 4 ^ 4 * ( 4 * 4 * 4 - 4 - 4 - 4 )` ::::::: `0xDC00 =  4 ^ ( 4 + 4 ) - ( 4 * ( 4 + 4 ) + 4 ) * ( 4 ^ 4 )` ::::::::: `65,536 = 4 ^ (4 + 4)` ::::::::: `1,114,112 = ( 4 + 4 ) ^ 4 * ( 4 * 4 + 4 ^ 4 )`

Comment: @JulesSam.Randolph : and to check any code-point whether it falls within :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::`0xD800 - 0xDFFF`, a quick and dirty trick is to simply check :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: `floor( code-point / 2048 ) == 27`