# Translate string to emoji in c#

Tags: c#, unicode, emoji

How to turn such a string into an emoji? 1F600 =>  or 1F600 => \U0001F600 or 1F600 => 0x1F600

I spent a few days but I still didn't understand how to translate a string like 1F600 into emoji

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to convert the value to the code point then get the character at that code point:

```
var emoji = Char.ConvertFromUtf32(Convert.ToInt32("1F600", 16));
```

[Demo on dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uPMRor)

Comment: Much easier than my answer; I wasn't aware of `Char.ConvertFromUtf32`.

Answer (score 1):

The string "1F600" is the hexadecimal representation of a Unicode code point. As it is not in the [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane), you either need UTF32 or a [UTF16 surrogate pair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836319/utf-16-encoding-why-using-complex-surrogate-pairs) to represent it.

Here is some code to perform the requested conversion using UTF32 representation:

1. Parse as 32-bit integer:

   `var utf32Char = uint.Parse("1F600", NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);`
2. Convert this to a 4-element byte array in litte-endian byte order:

   ```
   var utf32Bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(utf32Char);
   if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
       Array.Reverse(utf32Bytes);
   ```
3. Finally, use [Encoding.UTF32](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.utf32) to make a string from it.

   ```
   var str = Encoding.UTF32.GetString(utf32Bytes);
   Console.WriteLine(str);
   ```